# Python: Working with Pool, apply_async and join

Tags: python, python-2.7, asynchronous, subprocess, python-multiprocessing

I need to run a shell script that fetches a file from server and writes to the disk based on the arguments that are passed to it. I need to run this script for around 20+ different arguments and therefore need to run it in parallel for each argument.

I tried to accomplish this using `Pool`, `apply_async` and `join` in python. But it does not seem to work. Below is the code:

```
  import yaml
  from subprocess import call
  from multiprocessing import Pool

  feeder_server_conf = "/etc/feeder-servers.conf"
  with open("feed_conf.yaml", "r") as stream:
        feeds = yaml.load_all(stream)
        pool = Pool()
        for feed in feeds:
            for key, value in feed.items():
                keep_count_present = False
                name = value['name']
                age = value['age']
                if 'keep-count' in value:
                    keep_count = value['keep-count']
                    keep_count_present = True

                print "Pulling feed..."

                if keep_count_present:
                    command = "/usr/bin/pull-feed --name " + name + " --config " + feeder_server_conf + " --age " + str(age) + " --keep-count " + str(keep_count)
                else:
                    command = "/usr/bin/pull-feed --name " + name + " --config " + feeder_server_conf + " --age " + str(age)
                pool.apply_async(call, command.split())

        print "Waiting for pull-feeds to finish..."
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

The code just prints the following output and exits without pulling any of the files. Not sure what I am missing here. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
Pulling feeds...
Pulling feed...
Pulling feed...
Pulling feed...
Pulling feed...
Pulling feed...
Pulling feed...
Pulling feed...
Pulling feed...
Pulling feed...
Pulling feed...
Pulling feed...
Pulling feed...
Pulling feed...
Pulling feed...
Pulling feed...
Pulling feed...
Pulling feed...
Pulling feed...
Pulling feed...
Pulling feed...
Pulling feed...
Waiting for pull-feeds to finish...
```

The script that I am trying to execute works fine when ran individually (and so is not the culprit). I want the code to wait till all the files are pulled. Not sure what I am missing here. Am I not using the constructs in the correct way? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Replace `call` with `check_call` and then you will get an exception when an error occurs, instead of silently failing.

Comment: Didn't help. Still got the same output and nothing else.

Comment: Quick suggestion: create your pools in a `try` catch with `pool.close()` in the `finally` section (or better still, use `with` statement, if possible) to avoid leaving a cess`pool` of processes running in case the code in the middle throws an exception.

Comment: @musically_ut: Will make that change. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is a simple one, as described in [documentation of subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) `call`'s first argument is a **list**, but `apply_async` function applies the list from it's second argument as `function(*args)` would, that means your call will end up looking like this `call('/usr/bin/pull-feed', '--name', ...)` which is not how you use `call`. All you need to do is replace `pool.apply_async(call, command.split())` with `pool.apply_async(call, [command.split()])` to pass your command as a list to the first argument of `call`, the final command, used by `apply_async` will look like this `call(['/usr/bin/pull-feed', '--name'])`.

Comment: This fixes it. Thanks!